# How to use in Ruby variable arguments with "#{...}?

Tags: ruby, string, string-substitution

I want to have a method like this:

```
def process(text, *parameters)
   new_text = ...
end
```

where calling the function with

```
process("#{a} is not #{b}", 1, 2)
```

resulting in `new_text` being `1 is not 2` and calling the function with

```
process("#{a} does not exist", 'x')
```

resulting in `new_text` being `x does not exist`.

Or using an alternative way instead of using `"#{...}"` (e.g. #1, #2) to pass a string for arguments which are filled in/substituted.

Comment: Ruby has some keywords it needs for itself. Words like `end`, `return`, `next`, `if` and so on. `do` is one of them. Sometimes you can use them for your self, but it is confusing.

Comment: @steenslag good point, I adapted the question (maybe that's why someone downvoted my question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can to something like this:

```
def format(text, *args)
  text % args
end

format("%s is not %s", 1, 2)
# => "1 is not 2"

format("%s does not exist", 'x')
# => "x does not exist"
```

See [`String#%`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/String.html#method-i-25) and [`Kernel#sprintf`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf)

Because the above method uses `String#%` internally it is actually shorter to use `String#%` directly then wrapping it into another method:

```
"%s is not %s" % [1, 2]
# => "1 is not 2"

"%s does not exist" % 'x'
# => "x does not exist"
```

Note that multiple arguments must be passed in as an array in this example.

Comment: I improved the question to make it more clear (hopefully).  I mean a more generic method, so I can call it with any arbitrary arguments (depending on the string).

Comment: Updated my answer to address the changed question.

Comment: ...Except that this method is pretty pointless, since you might as well just use [`Kernel#sprintf`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) directly!

Comment: @TomLord in what way is `Kernel#sprintf` better than `text % args`?

Comment: It's not. They're basically the same thing. My point was that there's little point defining your own `format` method if all it's going to do is call `sprintf` under the hood. You might as well just call `sprintf` directly, no?